# Tensorflow .pb file only in Android is enough

Tags: android, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

I am working on image classification and I need some advice. am building large image classifier using keras with backend tensorflow because I want to use that model for Android application so I trained it and convert those checkpoints into protobuf (.pb) file . In many examples I saw 2 files when they export to android asset folder those are protobuf file and label.txt file so is that okay to use only protobuf file on android? 
  Thank you!

and here is the source code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Dense,Flatten,Dropout,Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras 
import keras.backend as k
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
print(keras.__version__)
print(tf.__version__)
import os
train_df = pd.read_csv('fashionmnist/fashion-mnist_train.csv',sep=',')
test_df = pd.read_csv('fashionmnist/fashion-mnist_test.csv',sep=',')


train_data =np.array(train_df,dtype = 'float32')
test_data = np.array(test_df,dtype = 'float32')
x_train = train_data[:,1:]/255
y_train = train_data[:,0]
x_test = train_data[:,1:]/255
y_test = train_data[:,0]
x_train,x_validate,y_train,y_validate=train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 12345)
image = x_train[50,:].reshape((28,28))
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

image_rows =28
image_cols= 28
batch_size =100
image_shape =(image_rows,image_cols,1)



x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],*image_shape)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],*image_shape)
x_validate = x_validate.reshape(x_validate.shape[0],*image_shape)


def build_network(is_training=True):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=image_shape,  padding='same',name="1_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',name="2_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name="1_pool"))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',name="3_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3, 3), padding='same',name="4_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name="2_pool"))

    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3, 3),padding='same',name="5_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3),padding='same',name="6_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name="3_pool"))

    model.add(Conv2D(256,(3, 3), padding='same',name="7_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same',name="8_conv"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name="4_pool"))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512,name="fc_1"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))


    if (is_training):
        #model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
        #model.add(Dropout(0.5, name="drop_1"))
        model.add(Lambda(lambda x:k.dropout(x,level=0.5),name="drop_1"))



    model.add(Dense(10,name="fc_2"))
    model.add(Activation('softmax',name="class_result"))
    #model.summary()
    return model


    tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
k.set_session(sess)
model=build_network()

history_dict = {}
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])




class TFCheckpointCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self,saver,sess):
        self.saver=saver
        self.sess=sess

    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,log=None):
        self.saver.save(self.sess,'fMnist/ckpt',global_step=epoch)


tf_saver= tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
checkpoint_callback= TFCheckpointCallback(tf_saver,sess)
%time
tf_graph=sess.graph
tf.train.write_graph(tf_graph.as_graph_def(),'freeze','fm_graph.pdtxt',as_text=True)
%time
history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=50,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
                    shuffle=True,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_validate,y_validate)
                   )

sess.close()


model_folder='fMnist/'
def prepare_graph_for_freezing(model_folder):
    model=build_network(is_training=False)
    checkpoint=tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    input_checkpoint=checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
    saver=tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
        k.set_session(sess)
        saver.restore(sess,input_checkpoint)
        tf.gfile.MakeDirs(model_folder+'freeze')
        saver.save(sess,model_folder + 'freeze/ckpt',global_step=0)


def freeze_graph(model_folder):
    checkpoint =tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    print(model_folder+'freeze/')
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
    absolut_model_folder="/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    output_graph=absolut_model_folder + "/fm_freazen_model.pb"
    print(output_graph)
    output_node_name = "class_result/Softmax"
    clear_devices = True
    new_saver=  tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta',clear_devices=clear_devices)

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()


    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess2:
        print(input_checkpoint)
        new_saver.restore(sess2,input_checkpoint)

        output_graph_def=graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess2,
        input_graph_def,
        output_node_name.split(","))

        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph,"wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph."% len(output_graph_def.node))
tf.reset_default_graph()
prepare_graph_for_freezing("freeze/")
freeze_graph("freeze/")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use the model on Android, you'll need to convert it to TensorFlow Lite first. This [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite) might help. The model will return indices and probabilities. If you want to convert the numerical index to a label, you'll need the labels.txt file for that mapping.

Alternatively, you can build your image classification model using [AutoML in ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-image-labeling). The client library takes care of doing that mapping automatically.

Comment: yes you got the point ! i want  to convert the numerical indices this given by the Tensorflow in to a label but I don't know how I do have all checkpoints and meta datas including .pb file. am searching for available tutorial but I did not find one please if you know how show me?

Comment: Did you try the codelab I linked to? It should have what you are looking for.

Comment: The codelab I linked to has a sample app that uses a TFlite model. Did you try that?